# How to match "$^$" in a string using str_view in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to create a code that would find "$^$" in the end (or beginning of a string).

Here is the code I have

```
library(stringr)
literalstring <- c("$$^dfgerg$^$", "$^$sgsgr", "gheugberhu$^$fgdbrbe")
```

Here I create a random string to test my code

```
str_view_all( literalstring, "($^$)$" , match=TRUE)
str_view_all( literalstring, "^($^$)" , match=TRUE)`
```

Here the $ after ($^$) is to specify that I can to find the $^$ that are at the end in the strings. The reverse applies to the "^($^$)"

Neither of these returns what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Look at

```
?regex
```

... to find the full list of meta-characters. (Clearly both "^" and "$" will be in that vector since they signify the empty beginning and ends of strings. The meta-characters all need to be escaped (preceded with *two* backslashes) when used outside of character-classes in an R pattern. (Since "^" also has special rules inside character-classes, I'm not using "[$][^][$]".) So try this:

```
str_view_all(literalstring, "(\\$\\^\\$$)$|^(\\$\\^\\$)" , match=TRUE)
```

The vertical bar or "pipe" is the regex (and R) OR-operator. But I misread your request and the answer would be:

```
end_loc <- str_view_all(literalstring, "\\$\\^\\$$" , match=TRUE)
beg_loc <- str_view_all(literalstring, "^\\$\\^\\$" , match=TRUE)
```

Comment: I thought the code should be reduced by one "$"? Please fix me if I'm wrong.                             
str_view_all(literalstring, "(\\$\\^\\$)$|^(\\$\\^\\$)" , match=TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

The `rex` package is really useful for specifying `regex`. In particular, it auto-escapes specials.

```
library(stringr)
library(rex)

rex("$^$")
#> \$\^\$

literalstring <- c("$$^dfgerg$^$", "$^$sgsgr", "gheugberhu$^$fgdbrbe")
str_view_all(literalstring, rex(("$^$" %if_prev_is% start) %or% ("$^$" %if_next_is% end)))
```

shows matches

[image]

The matching `regex` here (which matches the other answer up to the lookarounds) is

```
(?:(?:(?<=^)\$\^\$)|(?:\$\^\$(?=$)))
```

but the `rex` description reads:

- `$^$` if it follows directly after the start,
- or
- `$^$` if it is followed directly by the end.